# setOnClickListener error Null object

Tags: java, android

I saw many questions like mine
and I try to fix my codes but failed...
this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText usernameEditText;
EditText passwordEditText;
public Button saveme;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

    saveme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginn);
    saveme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
                String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();
                // CALL GetText method to make post method call
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://fb.facenegah.com/android/login.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", givenUsername));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", givenPassword));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                bread.show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //   content.setText(" url exeption! " );
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is my xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ایمیل/شناسه کاربری"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="رمز عبور"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:width="150dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ورود"
    android:id="@+id/loginn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

But I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

What is the issue?

Comment: 1. you missed `setContentView`. 2. network call on ui thread. 3. using deprecated method

Comment: There is not having any set up of Layout please set the Layout for Activity as setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` insert `setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout);`

you need to make a request to a server in another thread. It might look like

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private Context context;

        public LoginTask(Context context, String username, String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://fb.facenegah.com/android/login.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                return responseText;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s != null) {
                Toast bread = Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                bread.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, you need to change your button handler

```
saveme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
            String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();
            new LoginTask(MainActivity.this, givenUsername, givenPassword).execute();
        }
    });
```

promise that will understand and not just copy it and forget it :-)

Comment: its work now but when im click on that button noting happen

Comment: @user1772630 coz your code is wrong. You cannot do network operation on ui thread. also you need to use HttpUrlConnection. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Comment: can you give me example i find it on internet

Comment: @user1772630 http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html. use asynctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: many thanks sir . but its have error on this line: Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  getApplicationContext() <--- this actully

Comment: if is external class you need add `Context` in `AsyncTask` constructor.

Comment: can you tell me please how shoud i do this?

Comment: and its still not post anything to that url

Comment: that's another story :-)

Answer (score 3):

You missed

```
 setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

in `onCreate(...)` before View initialized

Answer (score 0):

use

```
setContentView(YOUR_LAYOUT)
```

after `super(savedinstate)` method in `onCreate()` method.

like.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(YOUR_LAYOUT_HERE);
}
```